# Inline display for div within div

Tags: css, html, inline

I have a HTML page with structure like below:

```
<div id="frst">
FIRST
</div>
<div id="top">
    <div id="mid">
        <div id="bottom">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li>A</li>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>A</li>
            </ul>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS I have wrote :

```
#frst{
display:inline;
}
#top,#mid,#bottom{
display:inline;
}
.menu li
{
    display:inline;
}
```

I want to display the divs with `id` `first` and `top` inline. But its displaying `top` div below the div `first` ! How can I make them inline ?

Comment: I tested your HTML, looks like they are inline already?  Just put some content in `#top` like this `<div id="top">asdf...` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

use `display:inline-block;`

```
#top{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6JtWq/1/)